# Clone DOM multiple times with adding class pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, dom, duplicates, clone

I want to clone all containers with class "gallery" in pure Javascript and add a class to the clone.

**Start:**

```
<div class="gallery">content here</div>

<div class="gallery">other content here</div>
```

**Result:**

```
<div class="gallery">content here</div>
<div class="gallery test">content here</div>

<div class="gallery">other content here</div>
<div class="gallery test">other content here</div>
```

I've tried this kind of code, but it's not working. Help appreciated

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery');

for(let i=0; i < elements; i++){
    let clone = this.cloneNode(true);
    this.classList.add('test');
    this.after(clone);
}
```

Comment: "not working" isn't a [useful description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: `this` — why are you using `this`? What do you expect it to be? What do you want it to be?

Comment: You're looping over `elements` but not doing anything with `elements` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You use `this` in the for loop but that doesn't make any sense. You have to access your element with `elements` and the current index (`i`). Furthermore, you forgot `length` in your for condition to determine the length of the elements array.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { //You forgot length
  let clone = elements[i].cloneNode(true); //Using elements[i] instead of this
  clone.classList.add('test'); //Add class to cloned element
  elements[i].after(clone); //Insert cloned element after element[i]
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">content here</div>
<div class="gallery">other content here</div>
```